# Why does JPA/Eclipselink fire redundant database queries even with the BatchFetchType.IN hint?

Tags: performance, jpa, optimization, eclipselink

**Summary :**

I am trying to minimize the number of queries my JPA based java application makes to the database. I specified the `@BatchFetch(BatchFetchType.IN)` optimization hint, but I still see some extra queries that I would consider as redundant and unnecessary.

**Details:**

Considering a simple domain model: We have Invoice mgmt system. Invoice has OneToOne relationship with Order. We also have customer, which has OneToMany relationship with Orders. **(Customer 1->M Order 1<-1 Invoice)**. Find more [details here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077819/java-se/understanding-jpa-part-2-relationships-the-jpa-way.html). Find the complete [source code here](http://images.techhive.com/downloads/idge/imported/article/jvw/2008/01/jpa2-012008.zip).
Here is the entity definition, as it currently stands:

**Client.java (Excluding getters and setter**):

```
  @Entity(name = "CUSTOMER") 
  public class Customer {
    @Id //signifies the primary key
    @Column(name = "CUST_ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long custId;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", length = 50)
    private String firstName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer",targetEntity=Order.class,
            fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<Order> orders;
    }
```

**Order.java (Excluding getters and setter**):

```
 @Entity(name = "ORDERS")
 public class Order {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ORDER_ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long orderId;

    @Column(name = "TOTAL_PRICE", precision = 2)
    private double totPrice;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,  mappedBy = "order")
    private Invoice invoice;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CUST_ID", referencedColumnName = "CUST_ID")
    private Customer customer;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "ORDER_DETAIL", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID",    referencedColumnName = "ORDER_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PROD_ID",    referencedColumnName = "PROD_ID"))
    private List<Product> productList;

 }
```

**Invoice.java (Excluding getters and setter**):

```
@Entity(name = "ORDER_INVOICE")
public class Invoice {

    @Id
    // signifies the primary key
    @Column(name = "INVOICE_ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long invoiceId;

    @Column(name = "AMOUNT_DUE", precision = 2)
    private double amountDue;

    @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID")
    private Order order;

 }
```

With this model in place, I ran a simple test to fetch all the orders of a customer.

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory =  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testjpa");     
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    Customer customer = em.find(Customer.class, 100L);

    Collection<Order> orders = customer.getOrders();

    for(Order order: orders){
        System.out.println(order.getInvoice().getInvoiceId());
    }

    em.close();
```

Since everything was lazy fetched, we got four queries, as shown:

```
1398882535950|1|1|statement|SELECT CUST_ID, APPT, CITY, EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, STREET, LAST_UPDATED_TIME, ZIP_CODE FROM CUSTOMER WHERE (CUST_ID = ?)|SELECT CUST_ID, APPT, CITY, EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, STREET, LAST_UPDATED_TIME, ZIP_CODE FROM CUSTOMER WHERE (CUST_ID = 100)

1398882535981|0|1|statement|SELECT ORDER_ID, OREDER_DESC, ORDER_DATE, TOTAL_PRICE, LAST_UPDATED_TIME, CUST_ID FROM ORDERS WHERE (CUST_ID = ?)|SELECT ORDER_ID, OREDER_DESC, ORDER_DATE, TOTAL_PRICE, LAST_UPDATED_TIME, CUST_ID FROM ORDERS WHERE (CUST_ID = 100)

1398882535995|1|1|statement|SELECT INVOICE_ID, AMOUNT_DUE, DATE_CANCELLED, DATE_RAISED, DATE_SETTLED, LAST_UPDATED_TIME, ORDER_ID FROM ORDER_INVOICE WHERE (ORDER_ID = ?)|SELECT INVOICE_ID, AMOUNT_DUE, DATE_CANCELLED, DATE_RAISED, DATE_SETTLED, LAST_UPDATED_TIME, ORDER_ID FROM ORDER_INVOICE WHERE (ORDER_ID = 111)

1398882536004|0|1|statement|SELECT INVOICE_ID, AMOUNT_DUE, DATE_CANCELLED, DATE_RAISED, DATE_SETTLED, LAST_UPDATED_TIME, ORDER_ID FROM ORDER_INVOICE WHERE (ORDER_ID = ?)|SELECT INVOICE_ID, AMOUNT_DUE, DATE_CANCELLED, DATE_RAISED, DATE_SETTLED, LAST_UPDATED_TIME, ORDER_ID FROM ORDER_INVOICE WHERE (ORDER_ID = 222)
```

Since I don't want N+1 calls for getting Invoices, I thought of using batch fetch and reduce the total queries to 4 (One query to fetch Invoices for all the Orders of Customer). To do the same, I updated my Order entity, as shown:

**Updated - Order.java, Adding BatchFetch for Invoice. (Excluding getters and setter**):

```
 @Entity(name = "ORDERS")
 public class Order {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ORDER_ID", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long orderId;

    @Column(name = "TOTAL_PRICE", precision = 2)
    private double totPrice;

    @BatchFetch(BatchFetchType.IN)
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,  mappedBy = "order")
    private Invoice invoice;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CUST_ID", referencedColumnName = "CUST_ID")
    private Customer customer;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "ORDER_DETAIL", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID",    referencedColumnName = "ORDER_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PROD_ID",    referencedColumnName = "PROD_ID"))
    private List<Product> productList;

 }
```

I ran the same test again, and was assuming there will be 3 queries to fetch the data.(One for customer, One for Orders and One to batch fetch Invoices). However, eclipselink 
generates 5 queries for the same. Here are the queries:

```
1398883197009|1|1|statement|SELECT CUST_ID, APPT, CITY, EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, STREET, LAST_UPDATED_TIME, ZIP_CODE FROM CUSTOMER WHERE (CUST_ID = ?)|SELECT CUST_ID, APPT, CITY, EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, STREET, LAST_UPDATED_TIME, ZIP_CODE FROM CUSTOMER WHERE (CUST_ID = 100)

1398883197030|0|1|statement|SELECT ORDER_ID, OREDER_DESC, ORDER_DATE, TOTAL_PRICE, LAST_UPDATED_TIME, CUST_ID FROM ORDERS WHERE (CUST_ID = ?)|SELECT ORDER_ID, OREDER_DESC, ORDER_DATE, TOTAL_PRICE, LAST_UPDATED_TIME, CUST_ID FROM ORDERS WHERE (CUST_ID = 100)

1398883197037|1|1|statement|SELECT INVOICE_ID, AMOUNT_DUE, DATE_CANCELLED, DATE_RAISED, DATE_SETTLED, LAST_UPDATED_TIME, ORDER_ID FROM ORDER_INVOICE WHERE (ORDER_ID IN (?,?))|SELECT INVOICE_ID, AMOUNT_DUE, DATE_CANCELLED, DATE_RAISED, DATE_SETTLED, LAST_UPDATED_TIME, ORDER_ID FROM ORDER_INVOICE WHERE (ORDER_ID IN (111,222))

1398883197042|1|1|statement|SELECT ORDER_ID, OREDER_DESC, ORDER_DATE, TOTAL_PRICE, LAST_UPDATED_TIME, CUST_ID FROM ORDERS WHERE (ORDER_ID = ?)|SELECT ORDER_ID, OREDER_DESC, ORDER_DATE, TOTAL_PRICE, LAST_UPDATED_TIME, CUST_ID FROM ORDERS WHERE (ORDER_ID = 222)

1398883197045|0|1|statement|SELECT INVOICE_ID, AMOUNT_DUE, DATE_CANCELLED, DATE_RAISED, DATE_SETTLED, LAST_UPDATED_TIME, ORDER_ID FROM ORDER_INVOICE WHERE (ORDER_ID = ?)|SELECT INVOICE_ID, AMOUNT_DUE, DATE_CANCELLED, DATE_RAISED, DATE_SETTLED, LAST_UPDATED_TIME, ORDER_ID FROM ORDER_INVOICE WHERE (ORDER_ID = 222)
```

I didn't understand why the last two queries are being generated. Any help to explain what's going on would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding some debug statements to see when the last two queries are executed (ie is it on building the orders list, or when calling order.getInvoice()).  Also check that there aren't any methods within orders, Customer or Invoice that might access relationships why the objects are incomplete - such as in a toString method.

Comment: All the queries are executed on order.getInvoice() statement.

All the fields (including relationships) are used in toString method of every object; but since the orders (111,222) are already loaded in 2nd query, why the explicit call again for the order 222 in the 4th query?

Comment: You mean the last 3 are executed on the First order.getInvoice() call?  Try changing your toString method to prevent loading lazy properties, and/or add debugging to see if it is the cause of the queries being triggered.  You might set logging to finest so EclipseLink messages are shown as well as the SQL

Comment: I'm confused. The source code zip file contains build path and persistence.xml references to OpenJPA, not EclipseLink. Why exactly are you talking about EclipseLink all the time? Are you just confused yourself about the different JPA implementations and did you actually mean to say OpenJPA when you said EclipseLink, or did you accidentally provide the wrong source code file because you also tested with OpenJPA but discovered the same problem therein and thus  intented to ignore it?

Comment: Yeah, I changed the provider to EclipseLink instead of going ahead with OpenJPA. The code was shared to give you the actual data model in place, but I have changed persistence.xml and updated the provider to EclipseLink.

Comment: @chris Yes all the queries are being executed on order.getInvoice().getInvoiceId().

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like a bug/problem in EclipseLink due to the traversal of eager relationships in the object model that allows the loading of the second Invoice in the "in" before the Order that reference it is loaded.  This forces the Invoice to query for the Order in the database, instead of finding it in the cache.

You can fix this by using lazy fetching on the Invoice to Order relationship.  This delay will allow EclipseLink to fully build the object model, so that it will be in the cache when it is accessed.  The code in the question shows this relationship is marked as Lazy, but this is only a hint to JPA providers that cannot work In EclipseLink without the use of an agent or byte code weaving as described here:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving
https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Dynamic_Weaving

Weaving is not required for lazy collections, only for 1:1 and other optimizations.

Comment: Yes, using lazy works.  The issue is only when the invoice->Order relation is eagerly fetched.  If it is marked as lazy and weaving is used, it will not occur in my tests using your classes.

Comment: Any plans to resolve this in EclipseLink any time soon? Even in EclipseLink 2.6.3 this bug still exists.